# UI interaction logging for Shiny?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

Does Shiny (or is there a package) that enables logging of UI interactions in a Shiny app?  I'm looking at a project which requires prototyping a data dashboard product and collecting data for AB testing.  I would ideally like to use Shiny, given the data and analytics, but I'm not aware of and cannot find a package that monitors and collects that type of data.

Comment: [This](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html) might get you started?

Comment: How on Earth did I miss that?  Thank you!